# "Mocking" SP Calls (From Other SPs) While Using TST

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing

I have recently started testing Stored Procedures using TST (tst.codeplex.com) and find it quite useful - one drawback however is that we cannot isolate dependencies and 'mock' other SP/function calls (like we would do for C# object dependencies, for eg.). I don't mind spending some time in adding this functionality to TST or writing a new framework, but I really don't know how to even start about it.

Any ideas? Any help appreciated.

PS: I know SPs were never designed with testing in mind, but this can be great boon for legacy projects with 100s of SPs already present.

Answer (score 2):

Aiding the previous answer really, while the renaming approach is far from ideal, it does work. I demo-ed it on a blog post meant for SSDT Database Projects, but the principle is the same:

https://tangodude.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/ssdt-database-projects-mocking-database-objects-for-isolated-unit-testing-kind-of/

tSQLt has all-round better support to mocking though:

http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/isolating-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with something similar myself and I wonder if the following might be an approach to mocking SP's.

Just before running a test which requires a mocked SP the test framework should:

- rename the original SP (to eg: HiddenSp)
- create a new Sp with the same parameters
- in the new SP add code to check for those combinations of parameters for which a mocked response is required
- provide the mocked response if necessary
- or
- pass the request thru to the original SP
- execute the test
- delete the mock
- revert the name of the original SP

We are not using TST but methinks I'll be adding something like this to our (hand-rolled) SQL test framework. Wont get to it for a few weeks, so I'd like to hear if this works for you.